# Best design for data structure (big data)

Tags: java, hadoop, bigdata

I have a lot of pages (5.000.000.000+) and I need to build a reverse link structure. 
For each page, I need to extract all outbound links.

e.g. for original data.

```
www.mypage1.com = outbound1, outbound2, outbound3
www.mypage2.com = ouput4, outbound2, outbound1
```

expected result.

```
outbound1=www.mypage1.com,www.mypage2.com
outbound2=www.mypage1.com,www.mypage2.com
outbound3=www.mypage1.com
outbound4=www.mypage2.com
```

Actually, I'm using hadoop to map-reduce  and it's working fine. But after some analysis I realized that some urls had at least 500mb of inbound links information.

And 5.000.0000.000 pages times 500 mb is a lot of data ...

Each url is 100 bytes length, so my first hint is to make some kind of hash to decrease the size of each url. But this will add some overhead to the process because we need a service to retrieve a hash given a url and viceverse.

So, what do you think is the best approach? Any ideas?

Comment: you don't need a big data structure, you are probably need the oracle db.

Comment: 2.5 Exabytes? Really? Even if you could squeeze each URL into a single byte (via Magic™), you'd need 25 Petabytes. If you are indeed telling the truth, I suggest you talk to one of the specialists that are probably on your team (If they're not, hire some. They cost next to nothing compared to all the storage and computing power.)

Comment: Why would I lie about the problem ...? A simple "I don't know, I have never faced that kind of problem" should be enough ...

Comment: how are you storing links? Are they just other URLs?

Comment: I do not believe every URL has 500MB of data pointing to it, but only a few outlyers. Assuming an URL is in the order of 100 bytes long, this would mean 5.000.000 pages are linking to it. If that would be an average value for every url, then you would not even be able to store the original data. Btw: how many different outgoing urls do you have, approximately?

Comment: Yes, the links are URLS. (Joe K)

Comment: (Clemens Klein) I really don't know, but what you say make sense. Maybe would be a good idea to know the inbound links distribution, and just give special attention to the special cases (e.g. more than 10000+ inbound links)

Answer (score 1):

Despite of unrealistic task for single-person-team, i can suggest:

1. According to "power low" 500mb will have only few of links, most of them will have a small bunch of links. so you should reestimate your links distribution.
2. To compress links you can use trie on reverted links (i.e. com.google.mail).

Comment: I have done the link distribution, and I have a better idea of what to do, thanks! BTW, the reverted links is a good one, I will give a try.